# JS Rock Paper Scissors - playerSelection is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a JavaScript Rock Paper Scissors game. In the previous version of the game prompt was used to get playerSelection, but the aim of this version is to make it work with buttons.

When I try to run the game it says in the game() function, there is a referenceError: playerSelection is not defined.

I've been racking my brain trying to fix it but only further mess up the code and confuse myself. I would greatly appreciate any assistance!

```js
const options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
const paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
const scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");
//get player's selection
function clickListener (event) {
    const playerSelection = event.target.id;
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
}
rock.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
paper.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
scissors.addEventListener("click", clickListener);

function getComputerChoice() {
  const choice = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
  return choice;
}
//check the winner
function checkWinner(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return "Tie";
  } else if (
    (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") ||
    (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
    (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock")
  ) {
    return "Player";
  } else {
    return "Computer";
  }
}
// play 1 round 
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  const result = checkWinner(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  if (result == "Tie") {
    return "It's a Tie!";
  } else if (result == "Player") {
    return `You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;
  } else {
    return `You Lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  }
  
}
//game
function game() {
  let scorePlayer = 0;
  let scoreComputer = 0;
  console.log("Welcome!");
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
    if (checkWinner(playerSelection, computerSelection) == "Player") {
      scorePlayer++;
    } else if (checkWinner(playerSelection, computerSelection) == "Computer") {
      scoreComputer++;
    }
  }
  console.log("Game Over");
  if (scorePlayer > scoreComputer) {
    console.log("Player was the winner");
  } else if (scorePlayer < scoreComputer) {
    console.log("Computer was the winner");
  } else {
    console.log("We have a tie!");
  }
}
// Function to play the game one more time
const play = document.querySelector("#play");
play.addEventListener("click", playAgain);

function playAgain() {
  game();
}

game();
```

Comment: playerSelection is indeed nowhere defined in your game() function before it's used here: `console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));`...

Comment: actually `playerSelection` is set inside `clickListener ` being the click event handler for the buttons rock papers and scissors.. but it's defined in the function scope and declared as const! Pretty messed up indeed

Comment: Aside from `playerSelection` being out of scope, it isn't even defined until one of the buttons is clicked which is **after** you try to read it inside the `game()` function.

Comment: Should I rewrite my playRound() function and place clickerListener() function there?

Comment: you should do some rethinking... the play round button should be disabled until the choice are picked for both players. The `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` must be set without declaring them as `const` so that the first time someone does, it will be considered a global variable available from any scope. But yet the logic using them should check if they are set before performing its action, and anyway such logic should be triggered only when the right conditions are met (both players selected their choice)

Answer (score -2):

ReferenceError is because the playerSelection variable is not defined within the **game** function. You can pass playerSelection as a parameter to the **game** function, and you should also return the result of each round from the **playRound** function. I've tried to modified above code, havn't tested but you can check yourself.

***Code:***

```
const options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
const paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
const scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");

// Initialize playerSelection
let playerSelection = "";

// Get player's selection
function clickListener(event) {
    playerSelection = event.target.id;
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
}

rock.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
paper.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
scissors.addEventListener("click", clickListener);

function getComputerChoice() {
    const choice = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
    return choice;
}

//check the winner
function checkWinner(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
    return "Tie";
  } else if (
    (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "scissors") ||
    (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == "paper") ||
    (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock")
  ) {
    return "Player";
  } else {
    return "Computer";
  }
}

// play 1 round 
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  const result = checkWinner(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  if (result == "Tie") {
    return "It's a Tie!";
  } else if (result == "Player") {
    return `You Win! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;
  } else {
    return `You Lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  }
}

// Game
function game(playerSelection) {
    let scorePlayer = 0;
    let scoreComputer = 0;
    console.log("Welcome!");
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
        const result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        console.log(result);
        if (result === "You Win!") {
            scorePlayer++;
        } else if (result === "You Lose!") {
            scoreComputer++;
        }
    }
    console.log("Game Over");
    if (scorePlayer > scoreComputer) {
        console.log("Player was the winner");
    } else if (scorePlayer < scoreComputer) {
        console.log("Computer was the winner");
    } else {
        console.log("We have a tie!");
    }
}

// Function to play the game one more time
const play = document.querySelector("#play");
play.addEventListener("click", playAgain);

function playAgain() {
    game(playerSelection);
}

// Start the game
game(playerSelection);
```

Comment: `game(playerSelection);` — At that point `playerSelection` is an empty string, so that won't work

Comment: "havn't tested" — that was a mistake

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you declare `playerSelection` in local environtment of `clickListener` function. So this variable can't be accessed in `game` function. But you declare `computerSelection` in `game` function, so there are no problems with that.

For more info you can check this book: https://javascript.info/closure

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).